# NavigationBar overlays my icon in Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, navigationbar

I have implemented an Android application for playing movies. I have an issue with `Toolbar` and `NavigationBar`. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

You can see that Settings icon is under the NavigationBar and it is unable to press it. I need to move this icon to the left of NavigationBar.

My style for activity follows.

```
<style name="VideoActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/VideoPlayer.PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/VideoPlayer.ListPopupWindow</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/VideoPlayer.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
</style>

<style name="VideoPlayer.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/VideoPlayer.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
</style>
```

I tried to set `fitsSystemWindows` attribute of my `Toolbar` to `true`, but it does not work.

Also I know I can set the `marginRight` to my `Toolbar`, but there are some other devices, which don't have NavigationBar, so it does not make sense to do this.

Can you help me, please? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

My layout of activity is attached below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/root_view"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent" >-->

    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_single_root"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/menu_list"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And layout with Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
/>
```

Comment: How does the xml of your activity look like where you add your toolbar ?

Comment: @JasonSaruulo See my update, please.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Or try by changing

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

to

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from your DrawerLayout.

Comment: Now my icon is not under the NavBar, but video does not cover the whole screen. My NavBar has to overlay my content of video.

Comment: You can hide the Navigation bar to get full screen.look into this http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html. You can control Navigation bar visibilty using http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: I am already using flags, which are mentioned in referenced articles, to achieve this. I didn't have the problem when I was targeting SDK version 18. When I started with targeting SDK version 22, problem occurs.